# pytest - Different results via VSCode and via command line

Tags: visual-studio-code, pytest, vscode-debugger, pytest-cov

For some reason I have a lot more test failures using **pytest** according to VSCode than I can see via the command line...

[image: I have a lot more test failures according to VSCode]

**What could be happening?**

**NOTE:** When I run **pytest** directly via CLI (Linux) I get exactly the same results seen in the "DEBUG CONSOLE".

**Tks!**

Comment: Do you need any other information? 

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the plugin has not run the tests with the same parameters as you do. Did you see the plugin output?

Example:

[image]

Comment: Yes, I even tested using the exact same command exposed by VSCode. Tks! 